# Dreamweaver - Using Regex to Remove CSS elements

Tags: css, regex, dreamweaver, replace

I have been trying to find away to so some simple find and replace in dreamweaver, I know it is possible, but I just can't get the right string combo. Had a read through some Adobe guides and other tutorials but they all seem to make no sense.

Essentially I want to strip out all css that creates rounded corners in all the open css files I am working on.
The css files contain reference to -webkit-border-radius, -moz-border-radius, border-radius but there are many different radius setup such as :4px or :4px 0 etc.

So I want to find ((-webkit-border-radius:) + (ANY ALPHANUMERIC);) and replace with nothing so that it deletes ALL instances of -webkit-border-radius no matter what px values have been used.

I will then use the same expression and just replace -webkit-border-radius with -moz-border-radius then just border-radius.

This should be possible, but can't work it out.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set your Find and Replace window to Regex.
2. Paste this into the 'find' box: `-webkit-border-radius:(.*);`
3. Clear your 'replace' box
4. Click 'Replace All'

You can use `(.*)` between two strings and it will find what you're looking for.

For example: `firstword(.*)lastword`.